# update multiple elements in an array in mongod php

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a document like

```
       {
 "_id": ObjectId("5b570181d2ccda05180055ed"),
 "VehicleNumber": "7656hhh",
 "DriverDetails": [
  {
   "DriverEntryId": "5016cfe5-e5ca-f9e1-35c6-1ab1d09230fb",
   "DriverId": ObjectId("5b488d70d2ccda01840078e6"),
   "StartDate": ISODate("2018-07-17T22:00:00.0Z"),
   "EndDate": ISODate("2018-07-27T22:00:00.0Z"),
   "Status" : "Active"
},
 {
   "DriverEntryId": "772cb165-33e3-6d92-ff04-007785e52a84",
   "DriverId": ObjectId("5b507122d2ccda04580006ca"),
   "StartDate": ISODate("2018-07-02T22:00:00.0Z"),
   "EndDate": ISODate("2018-07-18T22:00:00.0Z"),
   "Status": "Active"
},
 {
   "DriverEntryId": "12d1fa8a-9987-2c27-119e-80dd434c0534",
   "DriverId": ObjectId("5b488d70d2ccda01840078e6"),
   "StartDate": ISODate("2018-06-24T22:00:00.0Z"),
   "EndDate": ISODate("2018-07-31T22:00:00.0Z"),
   "Status": "Active" 
} 
],
..
}
```

I want to make status "Inactive" for all embedded document. I have tried below lines of code. It is not working... Please help!!!

```
      $this->collection->updateOne(
             array('_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id)
                  ),
             array('$set' => 
             array('DriverDetails.$.Status' => 'Inactive'
                  )
                )
           );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/)  the all positional operator to update every element in an array

```
$this->collection->updateOne(
 array('_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id)),
 array('$set' => array('DriverDetails.$[].Status' => 'Inactive'))
)
```

Equivalent to JS

```
db.collection.update(
  { "_id": "546djdhu99wijfejf9euf94ef" },
  { "$set": { "DriverDetails.$[].Status": "Inactive" }}
)
```

Comment: I am using 3.6 version.... it throws error message "<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method MongoDB\Collection::update()"